# VS 2015 Community Install Hangs During Install

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Installing VS 2015 Community on Window 7 box.  It went along for about 2 hours and then seemed to hang.  I decided to go to Task manager and see what was happening.  Big mistake!  At that point, I never got to Task Manager, the progress indicartor froze, and the entire system went totally unresponsive.  No keyboard or mouse input accepted anywhere.  Task Manager unaccessible.  Entire system hung.

All other issues reported here usually call for keying in something or mousing something.  No help to me when it appears the OS is hung up and not responding to anything.  This has been the case for over an hour.  They deal with VS "hanging".  My case has the entire system "hanging".

What do I do?  Should I pull the power?  what is that likely to do to my box if I do so?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not cool to use cleaning tools, but I ran CCleaner and Glary Utilities to clean my registry. After doing that and restarting, my botched installation came up at last. YMMV, FWIW.